# Symfony FromEvents 1 argument must be an instance of

Tags: php, symfony

The error here is not explicit, from what I think it is related just to a Type difference between parameters but i have not found the way to resolve this...
The `EventListener` is receiving 2 parameters but it doesn't provide the information of which of them is the "1" argument with the issue but I think it is the 2nd due to the error says *an instance of UserBundle\Form\FormEvent* on singular and the first argument is a generic event from the `FormEvents` class which is on plural.

Error Shown:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   UserBundle\Form\UserType::UserBundle\Form{closure}() must be an
>   instance of UserBundle\Form\FormEvent, instance of
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent given

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('username',HiddenType::class)
        ->add('firstname',TextType::class)
        ->add('lastname',TextType::class)
        ->add('email', RepeatedType::class, 
            array('type' => EmailType::class, 'invalid_message' => 'The email fields must match.','options' 
                => array('attr' => array('class' => 'email-field')),'required' => true, 'first_options'  
                => array('label' => 'Email'),'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirm email'),))
        ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, 
            array('type' => PasswordType::class, 'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.','options' 
                => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),'required' => true, 'first_options'  
                => array('label' => 'Password'),'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirm password'),))
        ->add('save',SubmitType::class)
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if ($data['firstname'] !== null && $data['lastname'] !== null){
                $username = $data['firstname']." ".$data['lastname'];
                $data['username'] = $username;
                $event->setData($data); 
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'user';
    }


}
```

I have followed the steps given by symfony documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `FormEvent` class import.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
```

Since you did not import it, it used the current namespace for the class (`UserBundle\Form\FormEvent`). But this class doesn't exist.